# python: check if all elements the same in an list

Tags: list, python-2.7, iterator, jupyter-notebook

I am using the following code to check if all the elements in a list are the same:

```
def sameItem(myList):
    return all(x==myList[0] for x in myList)
```

However, in my test case:

```
myL1 = ['dog','cat','dog']
sameItem(myL1)
```

returns `True`. Shouldn't it be False? Or did I have a bug in the `sameItem()` function?

Also, I am using Jupyter Notebook, could it cause any problem is this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. the first item is 'dog', and the second item 'cat'  is not equal to 'dog'. Shouldn't it return False?

Comment: No reproduce. It returns False for me

Comment: are u using python 2.7 as well?

Comment: Tried on both Python 2.7 and 3.4. Returns False.

Comment: Could it be all() function doesn't work for my python?

Comment: That makes no sense @Edamame, shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should be correct and works for me. As an alternative, you can try this method to double check, which is a one line that does the same thing

```
return myList[1:] == myList[:-1]
```

Comment: This works for me. May I ask what does it mean? Thanks

Comment: `myList[1:]` returns a list of all the elements in the list except for the first. `myList[:-1]` returns a list of all the elements in the list except for the last. You can try it out in a python interpreter to get a feel for the indexing. If this works, would you mind marking the answer as correct? That way it will be known that the issue was resolved. Thanks!